# Using RANK in HiveQL, dynamic limits

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, rank

Trying to perform a dynamic limit in hive sql via the rank function.

**PROBLEM:**
I want to use the limit from table A against table B to create the output. Example below.

**TABLE A:**

```
 ID   | Limit
 ------------
 123  | 1
 456  | 3
 789  | 2
```

**TABLE B:**

```
ID   | User
-------
123  | ABC
123  | DEF
123  | GHI
456  | JKL
456  | MNO
789  | PQR
789  | RST
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ID   | User
----------
123  | ABC
456  | JKL
456  | MNO
789  | PQR
789  | RST
```

Unfortunately you cannot do a dynamic limit (as far as I know) in hive sql. So I was trying to use rank. My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.users, c.rnk
FROM (
    SELECT b.id, b.user, a.limit, rank() over (ORDER BY b.id DESC) as rnk
    FROM a JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.id
    ) c
WHERE rnk < c.limit;
```

Currently I get the error:

```
ParseException line 3:9 cannot recognize input near 'rank' '(' ')' in from source 0
```

Any ideas why? Or maybe a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no column called limit in table b and no column user in table a

Comment: Fixed that... sorry just a typo. Still the same issue.

Comment: Why there is no `partition by`?  `rank() over (PARTITION by b.id ORDER BY b.id DESC)`

Comment: Also you can use `row_number()  over (PARTITION by b.id ORDER BY b.id DESC)`.   And the filter should be rnk  <=  c.limit, not just <

Comment: That was it! Thanks! If you post an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, c.users, c.rnk
FROM (
    SELECT b.id, b.user, a.limit, row_number() over (PARTITION by b.id ORDER BY b.id ) as rn
    FROM a JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.id
    ) c
WHERE rn <= c.limit;
```

In the above query `row_number()` will number rows after join, filter in the `where` clause will work as limit. `ORDER BY` is not necessary for simply limiting rows without any preference, replace `ORDER BY` with your rule, for example order by user.

Comment: Please edit your answer with explanation, or if you can't explain the code, please provide helpful link(s), but it's not preferred since links can expire or content may change. You should avoid posting answers in fashion that satisfy the rules of "gimme code please" questions.